# QGIS3 quits after PyQt Script 2 run

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

I wrote the PyQt script below and I am running it through QGIS3. When I run it for the first time after opening it in QGIS3, the application's window pops up smoothly. However, when I close the window and run the script, QGIS3 readily quits.  That may be something related to the event loop, but I'm unsure and don't know how to stop the QGIS3 shutdown for the subsequent runs.  Any hint on how to fix this issue?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QSize,
                          Qt)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                              QWidget,
                              QPushButton,
                              QMainWindow)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def _init_(self):
        super()._init_()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        button = QPushButton("Press Me!")

       
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(400,300))
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show() 
app.exec()
```

Comment: I realize this is just test code, but what are you really trying to do? Launching an application window within a running application is usually the shortest path to problems. Someone with more Qt experience will eventually wade in, but I expect the answer will be that there can only be one event loop and your embedded app closes the loop when it exits.

Comment: This was crossposted to the qgis mailing list and the user got help there already. Dear user, this is not nice because you make people try to help you without knowing they are duplicating redundant effort. Please be so kind and crosspost the answer from them mailing list here too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your code inside QGIS, you don't need the `QApplication()` call

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QSize,
                          Qt)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                              QWidget,
                              QPushButton,
                              QMainWindow)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def _init_(self):
        super()._init_()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        button = QPushButton("Press Me!")

       
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(400,300))

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
```